# Change the current value?

Tags: rust, sea-orm

How can I perform the following SQL statement in Rust with sea-orm?

```sql
UPDATE user SET balance = balance - debit
```

I've tried the following:

```rust
let updated = user::ActiveModel::update(&db)
    .set_expr(user::Column::Balance, user::Column::Balance - 100)
    .exec()
    .await.unwrap_or_default();
```

But this option doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to debit 100 from all users?

Comment: I didn’t fill the request with filters so that others could understand what I wanted.

Comment: ...I don't understand what you want. You want to user a filter to debit all users that meet a certain condition? Your code as written doesn't make any sense, my "you left out the WHERE clause and are about to wreck the database" alarm bells are ringing too loudly to make sense of this. Think about how you might react if you were answering someone else's question containing the SQL equivalent. You'd do them a solid and warn them, right?

Comment: Thanks for your concern and advice about "WHERE")

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: When your code produces an error, for best searchability you should add the full error message of your compiler (i.e. `cargo build`) to the question. If you can please [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
User::update_many()
        .col_expr(user::Column::Balance, Expr::col(user::Column::Balance).add(sum_num))
        .filter(user::Column::UserId.eq(user_id))
        .exec(&db)
        .await.unwrap_or_default();
```